# bi-directional access between local PC and AWS EC2 using AWS Client VPN Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, vpn, aws-vpn

I want to expose a web server (port 8080) on my local PC to the Internet with AWS Client VPN Endpoint. I can set up the VPN Endpoint and connect to the VPC successfully. I can ssh to an EC2 instance in the VPC. The EC2 is in a public subnet with CIDR `172.200.0.0/20` (The VPC CIDR is 172.200.0.0/16).

My PC was allocated with an IP `172.201.0.34` in CIDR range `172.201.0.0/16`.

Now I am trying to test the connection back to my PC

`nc -vz 172.201.0.34 8080`

But it failed because the ip `172.201.0.34` routes to the Internet Gateway so shown in the following route table.

| Destination | Target |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0.0.0/0 | igw-xxxx |
| 172.200.0.0/16 | local |

I am trying to add a route for `172.201.0.0/16` to target my Client VPN Endpoint, but AWS does not allow it.

How can I make my EC2 instance able to access my local PC when my PC is connecting to the Client VPN Endpoint?

Comment: Why do you use public IPs when you want to have private (through VPN) connection with your VPC and the instance?

Comment: @Marcin My final goal is to expose my web server on my local PC to the internet, so I associate the VPN with a public subnet. But currently I am not using any public IPs. I deployed an EC2 in the subnet without a public IP. Then I connected to the VPN and then ssh to the EC2 using its private IP. Now I am trying to access my local PC from the EC2. If this step is resolved, I will then proceed to set up a Network Load Balancer that can route traffic to my local PC.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted AWS Support and learned that this is not possible by design.